# Joint probability?

Tags: probability

Suppose that $3$ balls are chosen with replacement from an urn consisting of $5$ white and $8$ red balls. Suppose that the white balls are numbered, and let $Y_i$ equal $1$ if the $i$-th white ball is selected and $0$ otherwise. Find the joint probability mass function of $Y_1,Y_2$.

My attempt is: let $Y_1$ be  the event that the white ball number $1$ is chosen and $Y_2$ be the event that the white ball number $2$ is chosen

$$p(0,0)=11*11*11/13*13*13=1331/2197$$

$$p(1,0)=1*11*11/13*13*13=121/2197$$

$$p(0,1)=1*11*11/13*13*13=121/2197$$

$$p(1,1)=1*1*11/13*13*13=11/2197$$

but the sum is not $1$.
could someone help me to understand my mistake?

Comment: But $13^3=2197$.

Comment: Also:  You don't consider the placements for the two special balls.  In your formula for $p(1,0)$ for example, you assume that $W_1$ is chosen first.

Comment: Also:  you exclude cases where, say, $W_1$ is chosen three times.

Comment: @lulu is right that you haven't taken ordering into account, you also haven't taken into account drawing a target ball more than once.

Comment: In that case I choose the white ball number 1  but not the number 2.

Comment: in p(0,0) the white ball number 1 and the white ball number2 are not chosen      in p(1,0) the white ball number 1 is chosen and the white ball number2 is never chosen    p(0,1) the contrary      p(1,1)    the two balls are taken,     is it wrong?

Comment: is W1 the event that the first ball is chosen?

Comment: it seems to me that I didn't take ordering into account so I'm so sorry but I didn't understand your comments
Could you explain in other words, please?

Comment: Note;  if you want to address a comment to a user, you need to put @Anne or the like in it somewhere.  $W_1$ is just the first white ball.  For $p(1,0)$ you might draw $W_1$ three times, yes? Or two times. You don't consider this case.

Comment: So, for $P(1,0)$ :  To draw $W_1$ exactly once is $3\times 11^2 \times \frac {1}{13^3}$.  To draw $W_1$ exactly twice is $3\times 11 \times \frac 1{13^3}$.  To draw $W_1$ exactly three times is $\frac 1 {13^3}$.  Same for $P(0,1)$.  Can you handle $P(1,1)$?

Comment: @lulu $$P(1,0)=3*11^2*1/13^3+ 3*11*1/13^3+1/13^3=4753/2197>1?$$       $$P(1,1)=3*11/13^3+ 3*11/13^3=66/2197$$

Comment: Check your math.  Also, don't forget to put @username in your comment or the intended recipient won't get it.

Comment: For $P(1,1)$ you are again neglecting cases like $W_1W_1W_2$.

Comment: $$W1W2W2$$ and the other combinations---->$$3*11/13^3$$        $$W1W1W2$$ and the other combinations---->$$3*11/13^3$$

Comment: You lost me.  What is your answer for $P(1,1)$?

Comment: yes, i lost you, the one in which i'm neglecting the case W1W1W2

Comment: Well, I'm not understanding what your final answer for $P(1,1)$ is.  Can you just state it?

Comment: @lulu $$P(1,1)=3*11/13^3+3*11/13^3$$                  but why P(0,1)=4753/2197>1?

Comment: Not your username....the name of the intended recipient.  That answer for $P(1,1)$ is wrong for the reason I said.  You fail to count permutations of $W_1W_1W_2$ and $W_2W_2W_1$.

Comment: I didn't understand , If have 1 time W1 e two times W2 I can have W1W2W2, W2W1W2, W2W2W1, If have 2 times W1 e 1 time W2 I can have W2W1W1, W1W2W1, W1W1W2 in p(1,1)

Comment: Ok...so, again, what is your answer for $P(1,1)$?  Also, in computing $P(0,1)$ you appear to simply be adding incorrectly.  I should advise:  take greater care with your calculations.  If you constantly make careless errors, you'll never manage these sort of calculations (which are, admittedly, error prone).

Comment: i'm more and more confused...is it correct my interpretation of your P(1,0) in my post?  $$P(1,0)=3*11^2/13^3+3*11/13^3+1/13^3$$ if yes why is it >1? I'm trying to understand your way of solving the problem

Comment: For heaven's sakes.  As you have written, $P(1,0)=\frac {3\times 11^2+3\times 11 +1}{13^3}$, yes?  Just add the three terms in the numerator.

Comment: could you write your answers?

Comment: @lulu you are not clear at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $W_1$ denote the first white ball, $W_2$ the second.  We remark that there are $11$ balls aside from those two, thus the probability of choosing a neutral ball is $\frac {11}{13}$.  We will let $X$ denote a generic "neutral" choice.

$P(0,0)$:  We need each choice to be neutral so $$P(0,0)=\left( \frac {11}{13}\right)^3=\frac {1331}{2197}$$

$P(1,0)$:  here we have to distinguish a couple of cases.
Case I:  you choose $W_1$ exactly once.  Then there are $3$ places to locate the special ball, so $\frac {3\times 11^2}{13^3}$.

Case II:  you choose $W_1$ exactly twice.  Then there are $3$ places to locate the neutral ball so $\frac {3\times 11}{13^3}$.

Case III:  You choose $W_1$ three times. $\frac 1{13^3}$

Thus $$P(1,0)=\frac {3\times 11^2+3\times 11+1}{13^3}=\frac {397}{2197}$$

$P(0,1)=P(1,0)$ by symmetry.

$P(1,1)$:  you have to distinguish two cases.

Case I:  the third ball is neutral.  Then there are $3$ ways to place $W_1$ and then $2$ ways to place $W_2$ and then $11$ choices for $X$ so $\frac  {6\times 11}{13^3}$

Case II:  The third ball is one of $W_1,W_2$.  Then there are $6$ cases (two choices for the duplicate and three ways to place the odd man out).  Thus $\frac 6{13^3}$.

Thus $$P(1,1)=\frac {6\times 11+6}{13^3}=\frac {72}{2197}$$

Consistency check:  these should add to $1$.  Indeed $$1331+397+397+72=2197$$